# jQuery stop script execution after if condition within click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this table, the rows are selectable only when Approved? column is empty. User can also add text in Deny Reason column.

When Deny button clicked, I want to make sure all deny reasons are filled in all selected rows before the rest of action can be executed. I tried to use `return false` , `e.stopPropagation()` , `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` and none of those works. As you can see in my example, `alert("test")` will always be executed. I want to stop that. Could you help?

```js
$(function() {

    var table = $("#myDataTable").DataTable({
        info: false,
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        sorting: false
    });

    $("#myDataTable tbody").on('click', 'tr', function() {
        var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var rowText = tr.children("td").text();
        var approveDeny = tr.children("td:nth-child(2)").text();

        if (approveDeny == "") {
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        }
    });

    $("#myDataTable tbody tr td:nth-child(4)").click(function(e) {
        if ($(this).prev().prev().text() == "") {
            var text = $(this).text();
            $(this).text('');
            $('<textarea />').appendTo($(this)).val(text).select().blur(function() {
                var newText = $(this).val();
                var parentCell = $(this).parent();
                parentCell.find('textarea').remove();
                table.cell(parentCell).data(newText).draw();
            });
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $("#btnDeny").click(function(e) {
        table.cells('.selected',3).every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {         
            var data = this.data();
            if(data == "") {             
             alert( rowIdx + " is empty, you have to fill it.");
              return false;
            }
            console.log(data);
        });        
        alert("test");
    });


});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="myDataTable" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Approved?</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Deny Reason</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1">
            <td>Mickey Mouse</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>1/1/2016</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2">
            <td>Minnie Mouse</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1/3/2016</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="3">
            <td>Donald Duck</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1/5/2016</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnApprove" value="Approve">
    <input type="button" id="btnDeny" value="Deny">
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to be working well. The alert('test') will always run because it is out of the scope of your .every() function within the click function. Not sure what the issue is

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve. As it is, in your listener you have a call to every which will call the function you give it. After the every call finishes the function you give to the event listener will continue. You can't stop the execution of the click handler from inside the function given to every.

Comment: What I want to accomplish is that I do not want the alert to be executed after the if condition is met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variable outside of the scope of your inner `.every()` function and change it within that function so you know if the data is valid or not.

```
$("#btnDeny").click(function(e) { // Outer scope function 
    var valid = true;
    table.cells('.selected',3).every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) { // inner scope function     
        var data = this.data();
        if(data == "") { 
            valid = false;
            alert( rowIdx + " is empty, you have to fill it.");
        }
    });
    if (valid)
        alert("Data valid");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Right, you need to assign the boolean output of every() to a variable, and then execute your alert only if that variable is true. Right now the result of the every() call is ignored, and the alert is executed regardless. Something like:

```
var isValid = table.cells('.selected',3).every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
    var data = this.data();
    if(data == "") {                
        alert( rowIdx + " is empty, you have to fill it.");
        return false;
    }
    console.log(data);
});
if (isValid) {
    alert("test");
}
```

Comment: When I test it, isValid in console.log show me as an object instead of true or false. Thus the checking was not correct. What did I miss?

Comment: The native javascript Array.prototype.every method returns a boolean, so if your every() call is returning an object I'd guess that it's not actually the native javascript method. It's possible that DataTable has overridden it. In any case, look inside the object you're getting and see if you can derive "isValid" from its content.

Comment: You are right murdock, I have to get an javascript array from DataTable then I can check on that.